# Select rows that where a change has occurred in a field and join them to another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I have the following two tables:

```
Table 1
datetime (datetime)
code1 (int)
code2 (int)

Table 2
code2 (int)
description (text)
```

Lets say an example of the data is:

Table 1

```
   DateTime                 Code1 Code2
** 14/11/2016 6:55:00 PM    6     21
   14/11/2016 6:56:00 PM    6     21
** 14/11/2016 6:57:00 PM    6     23
** 14/11/2016 6:58:00 PM    6     28
   14/11/2016 6:59:00 PM    6     28
   14/11/2016 7:00:00 PM    6     28
** 14/11/2016 7:01:00 PM    6     22
** 14/11/2016 7:02:00 PM    6     23
   14/11/2016 7:03:00 PM    6     23
   14/11/2016 7:04:00 PM    6     23
** 14/11/2016 7:05:00 PM    6     27
** 14/11/2016 7:06:00 PM    5     8
** 14/11/2016 7:07:00 PM    5     9
   14/11/2016 7:08:00 PM    5     9
** 14/11/2016 7:09:00 PM    5     11
** 14/11/2016 7:10:00 PM    5     12
   14/11/2016 7:11:00 PM    5     12
** 14/11/2016 7:12:00 PM    5     14
** 14/11/2016 7:13:00 PM    5     15
   14/11/2016 7:14:00 PM    5     15
** 14/11/2016 7:15:00 PM    5     17
```

I would like to run an sql-express-2012 query that will return only the starred rows and then join the returned data to the description table based on the code2 - resulting in the following output table:

Final output table

```
   DateTime                 Code1 Code2 Description
** 14/11/2016 6:55:00 PM    6     21    some text 
** 14/11/2016 6:57:00 PM    6     23    some text 
** 14/11/2016 6:58:00 PM    6     28    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:01:00 PM    6     22    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:02:00 PM    6     23    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:05:00 PM    6     27    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:06:00 PM    5     8     some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:07:00 PM    5     9     some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:09:00 PM    5     11    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:10:00 PM    5     12    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:12:00 PM    5     14    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:13:00 PM    5     15    some text 
** 14/11/2016 7:15:00 PM    5     17    some text
```

Regards, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that the granularity in the time column is fixed at one-minute intervals: (It also doesn't use, as requested, window functions.)

```
Select a.*, description
  From #tbl1 As a
  Left Join #tbl1 As b
    On a.datetime = DateAdd(Minute, 1, b.datetime)
    And a.code1 = b.code1 
    And a.code2 = b.code2
  Left Join #tbl2 On a.code2 = #tbl2.code2
  Where b.datetime Is Null;
```

Comment: Thanks, mendosi. I have only done a little bit of testing but this seems to work for me. I am however, a little confused by the
`
On a.datetime = DateAdd(Minute, 1, b.datetime)  
    And a.code1 = b.code1   
    And a.code2 = b.code2
`
Could you elaborate? Also how would I amend the code to select only the rows with Code1 = 3 for example?

Comment: @beliskna That is just testing to see if `code1` and `code2` were the same 1 minute in the future from the current row. If so then don't return the row. As to the other question, you would change the last line to `WHERE b.datetime Is Null And a.code1 = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to get every first row (based on datetime) for each group of `code1, code2`.

Use `row_number` analytic function to assign numbers and then take only the first for each group:

```
select
  first_occurence.datetime,
  first_occurence.code1,
  first_occurence.code2,
  table2.description
from (
  select *
  from (
    select
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by code1, code2 order by datetime) as rn
    from table1
    ) table1
  where rn = 1
  ) first_occurence
  join table2 on first_occurence.code2 = table2.code2
```

---

After going through your desired output again it seems like above may not be enough. I'm not sure about the logic but I assume that a particular hour in a day also makes the group (in your example `code1 = 6, code2 = 23`) so add this:

```
convert(varchar(10), datetime, 103) -- date without time
datepart(hour, datetime) -- only hour
```

To the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
select
  first_occurence.datetime,
  first_occurence.code1,
  first_occurence.code2,
  table2.description
from (
  select *
  from (
    select
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by code1, code2, convert(varchar(10),datetime,103), datepart(hour, datetime) order by datetime) as rn
    from table1
    ) table1
  where rn = 1
  ) first_occurence
  join table2 on first_occurence.code2 = table2.code2
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think the functions you have suggested are supported in sql-server-express

Comment: Check this: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/is-row_number-function-exist-in-express.2509/

Comment: I have run the command it reports the database version is 2012 - I am wondering if it is the reporting services element that doesnt support the funciton?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select only rows where `Code2` changes you can Partition over `code2`:

```
select DateTime, Code1, Code2 from
(select *, rownumber() over (partition by code2 order by datetime) c from table1 ) t
where c = 1
```

This is the difficult part, we can augment this with a join to `table2`:

```
select t.DateTime, t.Code1, t.Code2, t2.Description from
(select *, rownumber() over (partition by code2 order by datetime) c from table1 ) t
left join table2 t2 on t.code2 = t2.code2
where t.c = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think the functions you have suggested are supported in sql-server-express

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `LEAD` function:

```
WITH CteLead AS(
    SELECT *,
        ldCode2 = LEAD(Code2) OVER(PARTITION BY code1 ORDER BY datetime)
    FROM Tbl1
)
SELECT
    datetime, code1, code2, t2.description
FROM CteLead cl
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.code2 = cl.code2
WHERE
    code2 <> ldCode2
    OR ldCode2 IS NULL
ORDER BY datetime;
```

Comment: I don't have much success using the lead, lag and over statements with sql-server-express, they appear to be unsupported?

Comment: [SQL Server 2012 supports the LEAD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx).

Comment: But I am using sql-server-express 2012 and that reports to me that the function is unsupported - or maybe it is the reporting services that does not support the function?